# resteasy confusion between two URL

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have 2 different URLs :

```
GET /stuff/{id} (where id is an Integer)
GET /stuff/foo?bar={someValue} (foo is not an Integer, it is a hard coded String)
```

When calling `/stuff/foo&bar=someValue`, I have the following error:

```
Failed executing GET /stuff/foo&bar=someValue
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo&bar=someValue"
```

The code is :

```
@GET
@Path("/stuff/{id}")
public Response getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    // code
}

@GET
@Path("/stuff/foo")
public Response foo(@QueryParam("bar") String bar) {
    // code
}
```

I am using [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) and I would like to keep my URLs that way if possible. Obviously RESTEasy just tries the getById method where it should use the foo method.

How can I do to make this work in RESTEasy ? ("change your URLs" is not an answer without detailed explanations about RESTEasy limitations). I tried (to be sure) putting foo code before getById but I had the same error (of course).

Is there any priority notion between declared URLs ?

As a note : I already implemented that kind of URLs in another framework (python-flask) and it worked just fine : you just have to be careful to declare /stuff/foo *before* /stuff/{id} (specific case before a more generic one).

---

**EDIT**: I just made a stupid mistake ! I was calling `/stuff/foo&bar=someValue` where I should be calling `/stuff/foo?bar=someValue`. Thanks @Scobal for pointing it out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `GET /stuff/foo&bar=someValue`

You should be calling `GET /stuff/foo?bar=someValue`

RESTEasy is trying to parse `foo&bar=someValue` as the `{id}` field.

I can't give you an answer about RESTEasy URL priorities but you could do this:

```
@GET
@Path("/stuff/{id}")
public Response getById(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("bar") String bar) {           
    try { 
        int intId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        // do int id things
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        // do foo + bar things
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I think I will do something like /stuff/foo, since I didn't find a way to put some priority between URLs. (I'm not a fan of your try/catch suggestion)

Comment: Yep, it's not an ideal solution. I'd be interested to know if there is a way to do it directly with RESTEasy.

Comment: oh I made a mistake : I am calling GET /stuff/foo?bar=someValue already !